# is it possible to fixed the rust FFI unsafe code segment fault issue when interop with syntax C lib

Tags: c, rust

I need to invoke some C function from my rust project to parse the latex synctex file. After I add the C FFI invoke, the application come from a segment fault with the unsafe code. I have tried to dump the rust aplication and using rust-gdb to debugging the dump like this in alpine:

```
apk add rust-gdb
// open the core dump
rust-gdb hub-server core.22
```

and using bt command to show the recent stack trace:

```
/app # rust-gdb hub-server core.22
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-alpine-linux-musl".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from texhub-server...
[New LWP 24]
[New LWP 22]
[New LWP 25]
[New LWP 23]
Core was generated by `./hub-server'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 24)]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f0fb60d5043 in texhub_server::service::project::project_service::get_pdf_pos::hb310e6fc665715f6 ()
#2  0x00007f0fb61215c3 in actix_web::handler::handler_service::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::h39d982929516ac8a ()
#3  0x00007f0fb611a5d9 in <actix_web::resource::Resource<T> as actix_web::service::HttpServiceFactory>::register::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::h3bd02824b0edd4f6
    ()
#4  0x00007f0fb611a289 in <actix_web::scope::Scope<T> as actix_web::service::HttpServiceFactory>::register::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::h783ac7acd866effe ()
#5  0x00007f0fb613eca7 in actix_http::h1::dispatcher::InnerDispatcher<T,S,B,X,U>::poll_request::ha4f84a5821e588a5 ()
#6  0x00007f0fb60ef810 in <actix_http::h1::dispatcher::Dispatcher<T,S,B,X,U> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h0990c119c53c81bb ()
#7  0x00007f0fb60f32ed in <actix_http::service::HttpServiceHandlerResponse<T,S,B,X,U> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::hb8b9ff149f3fc186 ()
#8  0x00007f0fb61b6e55 in <actix_service::and_then::AndThenServiceResponse<A,B,Req> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h653ef60f84678589 ()
#9  0x00007f0fb60beda7 in tokio::runtime::task::core::Core<T,S>::poll::h5887eb0791d95431 ()
#10 0x00007f0fb61e0560 in tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll::h17564a689f284eaa ()
#11 0x00007f0fb6669d3b in tokio::task::local::LocalSet::tick::h7bb0abdadba8b00f ()
#12 0x00007f0fb647fb26 in <tokio::task::local::RunUntil<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h1f674f053295753b ()
#13 0x00007f0fb645edc4 in <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::hb6c0a60ccc0b4122 ()
#14 0x00007f0fb647e223 in tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Context::enter::hd61e38f74364c077 ()
#15 0x00007f0fb64735f0 in tokio::runtime::context::scoped::Scoped<T>::set::h3d287d08efa14f62 ()
#16 0x00007f0fb646cc15 in tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler::hb93173d8d88fa59b ()
#17 0x00007f0fb647e7ea in tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::block_on::hd292f5e65288f4ad ()
#18 0x00007f0fb64693f7 in tokio::runtime::context::runtime::enter_runtime::h716ffe00d79797d0 ()
#19 0x00007f0fb646f3dc in std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h12093c8b1ce41ac4 ()
#20 0x00007f0fb645ce0e in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::hcf492da42f2b3495 ()
#21 0x00007f0fb68de565 in alloc::boxed::{impl#47}::call_once<(), dyn core::ops::function::FnOnce<(), Output=()>, alloc::alloc::Global> ()
    at library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1985
#22 alloc::boxed::{impl#47}::call_once<(), alloc::boxed::Box<dyn core::ops::function::FnOnce<(), Output=()>, alloc::alloc::Global>, alloc::alloc::Global> ()
    at library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1985
#23 std::sys::unix::thread::{impl#2}::new::thread_start () at library/std/src/sys/unix/thread.rs:108
#24 0x00007f0fb6910405 in start () at ../src_musl/src/thread/pthread_create.c:203
#25 0x00007f0fb6911923 in __clone () at ../src_musl/src/thread/x86_64/clone.s:22
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
(gdb)
```

from this error dump, I could only know the error was come from the function `get_pdf_pos`, I could hardly know where is going wrong and have no clue to fixed this issue. This is the `get_pdf_pos` function look like:

```
pub fn get_pdf_pos(params: &GetPdfPosParams) {
    let proj_dir = get_proj_base_dir(&params.project_id);
    let pdf_file_name = format!(
        "{}{}",
        get_filename_without_ext(&params.file),
        ".pdf".to_owned()
    );
    let file_path = join_paths(&[&proj_dir, &pdf_file_name.to_string()]);
    warn!("pdf file path: {}", file_path);
    unsafe {
        let c_file_path = CString::new(file_path.clone());
        if let Err(e) = c_file_path {
            error!("parse out path error,{},{}", e, file_path.clone());
            return;
        }
        let c_build_path = CString::new(proj_dir.clone());
        if let Err(e) = c_build_path {
            error!("parse build path error,{},{}", e, proj_dir.clone());
            return;
        }
        warn!("start to get canner, file path: {}", file_path.clone());
        let scanner = synctex_scanner_new_with_output_file(
            c_file_path.unwrap().as_ptr(),
            c_build_path.unwrap().as_ptr(),
            1,
        );
        warn!("c scanner: {:?}", scanner);
        let tex_file_path = join_paths(&[proj_dir, params.file.clone()]);
        let c_tex_file_path = CString::new(tex_file_path);
        let node_number =
            synctex_display_query(scanner, c_tex_file_path.unwrap().as_ptr(), 1, 1, 0);
        if node_number > 0 {
            for i in 0..node_number {
                let node: synctex_node_p = synctex_scanner_next_result(scanner);
                println!("node...{:?}", node);
                let page = synctex_node_page(node);
                println!("page: {:?}", page);
                let h = synctex_node_visible_h(node);
                println!("h: {:?}", h);
                let v = synctex_node_visible_v(node);
                println!("v: {:?}", v);
                let height = synctex_node_visible_height(node);
                println!("height: {:?}", height);
                let width = synctex_node_visible_width(node);
                println!("width: {:?}", width);
            }
        }
        warn!("node_number result: {:?}", node_number);
    }
}
```

what should I do to fixed this segment fault issue? I am put the share library `libsynctex_parser.so` to the application root folder.

Comment: `#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()` usually means something bad happened to a function call.  I suspect Rust is having a problem finding one or more of your `synctex*` functions, and the internal function pointer is `NULL`, causing an attempt to run code located at `0x0000000000000000` and the resultant `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: thank you for the expain, I have test the code and runs fine in my local machine, but  not works in production environment. is it possible to capture the error in rust? current the whole application are crashed when access this function.

Comment: An easy diagnostic trick: the _poor man debugger_. Add a `dbg!("A");` with a different message before and after every call to the C libraries, then when your program crashes you will know which one is the offending call.